# How to allign windows together and move them as one unit?

Tags: qt, opencv, qt-creator

I'm trying to make created windows to (I'm using opencv's built in qt library, but I'm open to new methods) be aligned side by side and in a certain location on the user's screen, instead of being stacked on top of one another. Therefore, requiring manual moving around (a big waste of time...).

Here is what the current program looks like after clicking split channels.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR9Jh.png

Here is what I would like it to look like (I moved the windows in their place).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmuet.png

Here is the code that creates the windows.

```
void opencv_Window::Splitchannels(){

    if (!InputImage.empty()){

        Mat a;
        vector<Mat> chans;

        a = matArray[csIndex].clone();

        if (!a.empty()){
            splitchan = true;
            split(a, chans);

            namedWindow(ch1, 0);
            namedWindow(ch2, 0);
            namedWindow(ch3, 0);

            imshow(ch1, chans[0]);
            imshow(ch2, chans[1]);
            imshow(ch3, chans[2]);

            resizeWindow(ch1, window_width, window_height);
            resizeWindow(ch2, window_width, window_height);
            resizeWindow(ch3, window_width, window_height);

            if (chans.size() > 3){
                imshow(ch4, chans[3]);
                resizeWindow(ch4, window_width, window_height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [cv::moveWindow](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga8d86b207f7211250dbe6e28f76307ffb&gsc.tab=0)

Comment: since you are using Qt already for your main application, why don't you display OpenCV images in Qt widgets instead of using `cv::imshow()`?